# 2 different buttons to and

Tags: java, android

Im Playing around with some android development and im trying to create 2 buttons with 2 different functions.

When you start the app you get this screen with some buttons and then you choose which one.

till now this is what i got of code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button startGame = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ivenever);
        Button howTo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.howto);

        startGame.setOnClickListener(this);
        howTo.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()) { //Get the id of the button that was clicked
        case R.id.ivenever:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartGame.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.howto:
            Intent e = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HowTo.class);
            startActivity(e);
            break;
        }
    }
```

In my try of creating the buttons. Both buttons got each of their xml code and id. The StartGame.class is working fine but the howto button just makes the app crash.

**LogCat:**

```
04-15 15:21:43.403: E/AndroidRuntime(24075): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.name.name/com.name.name.HowTo}:   
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
Resource ID #0x7f05003e type #0x12 is not valid
```

HowTo.java file:
Package is included

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HowTo extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.id.howto);

        Button ivenever = (Button)findViewById(R.id.game);
        ivenever.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(HowTo.this, StartGame.class);
              }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat then

Comment: Please post your logcat o/p here...

Comment: Have you defined `how to` activity in manifest?

Comment: the error is in the `HowTo.java` file as when you click the button for it, the HowTo class gives error. You should post the code for this class or the logcat. The `MainActivity.java` is fine.

Comment: You make sure that your both Buttons belong to your `activity_main.xml` layout.

Comment: post the `activity_main.xml` and the stackrace

Comment: you need to post the fullstacktrace

Comment: I have added some from the logcat and the both buttons belong to my activity_main.xml.

Comment: @McBoman post `HowTo.java` that is where you have a problem

Comment: @McBoman - See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content of the layout to the activity. What you have  `setContentView(R.id.howto);` is wrong.

So change to

```
setContentView(R.layout.HowTo);
```

Comment: Thanks This was the right answer im kinda embarassed that i couldn't see that one xD thanks for the help :-)